# HTTP POST Vunerable to change?

Tags: security, http-post

I was wondering if anyone knows if the following scenario can happen.

Suppose I have dynamically generated a form that has check boxes for products specific to that customer. If the customer checks the boxes, the products will be deleted when form posted. The checkboxes are named after the productID.

Now my handler will check the response.form and parse the productID out, then delete the product from the database based on the productID.

Potentially could someone amend the post to allow other productIDs to be deleted, potentially everything in the product table by adding fake checkbox names to the POST?

If so, it would be easy to check prior to delete the productID is related to the authenticated user, and they have sufficient roles to delete, or to generate a nonce and label the checkboxes with that rather than their product ID, however I am not doing this at the moment. Any pointers to best practices for this would be good.

I have never considered this before, and wonder just how many people actually do this by default, or are there a million web sites out there vunerable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is **absolutely** possible that someone could build a custom POST request with any key/value pairs (including product ID values) and submit it to your application. The fact that the checkboxes are not on the form that the POST is *supposed* to come from is irrelevant from a security perspective.

When thinking about web application security, the client is a completely untrusted entity. You have to assume that your JavaScript validation will be bypassed, your SELECT elements can be altered to contain any value an attacker wants, and so forth.

So yes, you should validate that the current user is authorized to delete any product ID submitted to this handler.

I'm not necessarily convinced that you need to go the nonce-obfuscation route. It is an additional layer of security, which is good, but if you are performing proper authorization I don't think it's necessary.

My $0.02

Comment: Thanks for the response, good to know POST is not secure, it will mean I am much more stringent. I will definitely be putting more checks on the response to ensure that what I receive back is to be expected from that user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a problem. What you are describing is an example of the "Insecure Direct Object References" risk as defined by the [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/) (OWASP).

As to how common it is, it currently (2011) ranks 4th in the OWASP's list of top 10 most severe web application security risks. Details of how to prevent this can be found on the [OWASP page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

> How Do I Prevent Insecure Direct Object References?
>
> Preventing insecure direct object
>   references requires selecting an
>   approach for protecting each user
>   accessible object (e.g., object
>   number, filename):
>
> 1. Use per user or session indirect
>      object references. This prevents
>      attackers from directly targeting
>      unauthorized resources. For example,
>      instead of using the resource’s
>      database key, a drop down list of
>      six resources authorized for the
>      current user could use the numbers 1
>      to 6 to indicate which value the
>      user selected. The application has
>      to map the per-user indirect
>      reference back to the actual
>      database key on the server. OWASP’s
>      ESAPI includes both sequential and
>      random access reference maps that
>      developers can use to eliminate
>      direct object references.
> 2. Check access. Each use of a direct object reference from an
>      untrusted source must include an
>      access control check to ensure the
>      user is authorized for the requested
>      object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply validate the values you get against the values you provided? Example: You have provided check boxes for items 1, 2 and 3, 9. The user posts 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. You can find the intersection of the lists and delete that (in this case 1, 2, and 3 are in both lists).

Comment: Thanks I will look at this also, could be the cheapest way rather than going back to the database to check on POST.